# Move position of UIView with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, autolayout

I have following code to move position of `UIView` to other position

```
_completedStatusView.frame =
CGRectMake(153, _completedStatusView.frame.origin.y,
                     _completedStatusView.frame.size.width, _completedStatusView.frame.size.height);
```

However, the position doesn't move although when I do `NSLog`, it actually moves. Moreover, it works if I disable **AutoLayout**.

What is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect your view leading constraint as `IBOutlet` say `_completedStatusViewLeading`  then do the following

```
_completedStatusViewLeading.constant = 153.f;
```